Looking for a certain finite lattice
I don't think it actually exists, and it should be difficult proving that it doesn't (some background here), but is it possible to build a finite lattice $L$ where the only meet-irreducible elements are the coatoms and each coatom is greater than or equal to strictly more than $|L|/2$ elements?

This is equivalent to the union-closed sets conjecture. In fact, you don't even need to assume the meet-irreducibles are coatoms. See here

@GrantB. I know that formulation, but I don't think it is equivalent to my question, unless I am wrong. That one says that in every lattice there is a join-irreducible element such that the number of elements $\ge$ to that one are at most half of the elements. Dually I think that is equivalent to the existance of a meet-irreducible element such that the number of elements NOT $\le$ of that one are at least half of all elements. I think my formulation is only a special case of the union-closed sets conjecture, although more difficult than others.

Regardless of whether it's equivalent or only a special case, if you were aware of the connection you should have mentioned it in the question.

@FabiusWiesner I phrased my comment poorly; rather I meant that an example of the lattice you are asking for would disprove the union-closed sets conjecture. (I also don't understand what you said about dualization; the dual of the statement in the link would say "in any finite lattice, there is a meet-irreducible element $x$ such that the number of elements less than or equal to $x$ is at most half the lattice." Evidently your lattice would disprove that statement, which the link asserts is equivalent to union-closed sets.)

@GrantB. OK I get it now, thank you.
